# How can I change the label values inside the barplot in Julia?

Tags: colors, julia, size, text-alignment, bold

The script I used is:

```
using Plots

numbers = [2, 4, 2]
colors_1 = ["white", "red", "white"]
colors_2 = ["white", "yellow", "white"]
legend_text = "Graphic"
letters = ["A", "B", "C"] 

Plots.bar(numbers,
          color = colors_1, 
          background_color_legend = "white",
          foreground_color_axis = "white",
          foreground_color_border = "black",
          foreground_color_grid = "white",
          foreground_color_legend = "black",
          framestyle = :box, 
          framevisible = false,
          label = legend_text, 
          legendfontcolor = "yellow", 
          legendfontsize = 20, 
          linecolor = "white", 
          markercolor = "yellow", 
          markershape = :rect, 
          markershapecolor = "yellow", 
          markerstrokecolor = "yellow",
          markerstrokestyle = ":solid",
          markerstrokesize = 10, 
          seriestype = :bar, 
          series_annotations =  (letters, colors_2),
          size = (1000, 1000), 
          textposition = "auto", 
          xtickfont = "white", 
          ytickfont = "white",
          width = [0, 0, 0])
```

I try change the label color and size, and set the label with bold and align, but I can only change the color. I need help to change label with the size, bold and align.

Comment: Hey Diego, can you add a markdown code block to your example to make reproducing it easier? https://markdown.land/markdown-code-block

Comment: Sure. I added the markdown code block a few minutes ago.

Comment: Someone knows how to change label?

Comment: I still haven't been able to change the size of the letter within the bar graph or the position (into series_annotations). Someone how know to change this parameters?

Comment: So I had a hard time with every requirement but I was able to bold the text with `bar_plot = bar(
    letters,
    numbers,
    fillcolor=colors_1,
    yguidefont=font(10, "Arial", :bold),
    series_annotations=[latexstring("\\textbf{$letter}") for letter in letters]
)
` It might be useful to use https://docs.makie.org/stable/ instead as it's more customizable. Sorry I can't be of more help.